# Can't set 0 as integer

Tags: go, sqlite

I have simple function which updates my db. I use SQLite3 so I use `INTEGER` field as `bool`.

Here is this function:

```
func updateDevice(devID int64, videoPath string, active bool) {
        stmt, err := db.Prepare("UPDATE Devices SET CurrentVideo=?, Active=? WHERE ID=?")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error while preparing to update device with ID: %s: %s", devID, err)
        }

        res, err := stmt.Exec(videoPath, devID, active)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error while updating device with ID: %s : %s", devID, err)
        }
        rowsAff, _ := res.RowsAffected()
        if rowsAff > 0 {
                log.Printf("Successfully update device with ID: %v", devID)
        } else {
                log.Println("Didn't affect on any row")
        }
}
```

When I set `active` to `true` I get the message that I successfully updated the device, but when I want to set `active` to `false` I get this message: `Didn't affect on any row` and in a database, I have still old values.

Why when I use `false` as `active` I can't update this table? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Double check the order of the values you're passing to Exec with the order of the placeholders in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the exec you have to pass the values in the same order they had for the prepare.

You have this order in the prepare:

```
CurrentVideo=?, Active=? WHERE ID=?
```

it seems to me that in the exec you have reversed the "active" and "devID" values.

```
func updateDevice(devID int64, videoPath string, active bool) {
        stmt, err := db.Prepare("UPDATE Devices SET CurrentVideo=?, Active=? WHERE ID=?")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error while preparing to update device with ID: %s: %s", devID, err)
        }

        res, err := stmt.Exec(videoPath, active, devID)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error while updating device with ID: %s : %s", devID, err)
        }
        rowsAff, _ := res.RowsAffected()
        if rowsAff > 0 {
                log.Printf("Successfully update device with ID: %v", devID)
        } else {
                log.Println("Didn't affect on any row")
        }
}
```

try this way.